# 'Nullable object must have a value' when adding entity to set in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm having some trouble with adding an entity to a DbSet in EF Core. 
The entity looks like this:

```
public class Employee : TenantEntity
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

With this base class:

```
public class TenantEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid TenantId { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedUtc { get; set; }

    public DateTime? UpdatedUtc { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DeletedUtc { get; set; }
}
```

The exception occurs in this method:

```
public class MultitenantRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : TenantEntity
{

    ...
    public TEntity Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        entity.TenantId = TenantProvider.GetTenantId();
        entity.CreatedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;

        return Context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity).Entity;
    }
    ...
}
```

Specifically on the Add method on Set<>(). Just some more details, I set the DateTime type as `datetime2` within the DbContext.

Comment: Are you sure that UpdatedUtc and DeletedUtc  columns allow nulls?

Comment: You haven't changed any of the DbContext standard conventions that would alter the Id from being the identity/primary key on this table?

Comment: @AlexanderGoldabin Yes when I look at the table in db, the collumns UpdateUtc and DeleteUtc are set to nullable `datetime2`. CreatedUtc isn't which is expected behaviour.

Comment: @BryanLewis Nope, I did however modify the getter/setters on Id. Like this https://dotnetfiddle.net/YzMA2A

Comment: you should add a try catch block to see which property is throwing the error. Also, is `TenantEntity.Id` generated by the db?

Comment: Do breakpoint and find where error happens?

Comment: I don't see anything inherited from `Entity` in provided code

Comment: What kind of exception occurs?! you didn't mention it. could you add text of the exception?

Comment: Did you resolve this? I have the exact same error since upgrading to 3.1.2